# mustache, render string without knowing data structure

Tags: objective-c, json, mustache

I've got a json like this:

```
{
    "questionTemplate": "1",
    "answerTemplate": "1",
    "placeholders": {
        "qd0": "1",
        "qd1": "2",
        "qd2": "2",
        "qd3": "3",
        "qd4": "5",
        "qd5": "2",
        "qd6": "3",
        "qd7": "3",
        "ad0": "60",
        "ad1": "{{qd1}}+{{qd3}}",
        "ad2": "{{qd1}}+{{qd3}}+{{ad1}}",
        "ad3": "5",
        "ad4": "10",
        "ad5": "3",
        "ad6": "10",
        "ad7": "9"
    },
    "answeres": [
        {
            "r": "({{qd1}}+{{ad7}})*{{ad2}}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Where there's a string like `{{qd1}}+{{qd3}}` I should compute the sum of the values at the keys `qd1` and `qd2`. So I should substitute, with mustache, the values with the one stored in the referenced keys.

My problem is that this it completely generic: one json could be like this, another one will be different!

How could I do?

I was trying to understand how to use

```
+ (id)templateFromString:(NSString *)templateString
               error:(NSError **)error;
```

and

```
- (NSString *)renderObjectsFromArray:(NSArray *)objects error:(NSError **)error;
```

but i'm not sure if is what I need

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of GRMustache. Could you please provide 1. some real (not too big) data and templates, 2. the code you have written so far, 3. the expected result? I'll help you the best I can.

Comment: Hi Gwendal! Nice to meet you and thank you for your reply! That json IS my data structure and my template. As far as I understand, with mustache I must know the name of the key i need to replace in a template, right? My problem is that i know this information at runtime, when i parse the json. For now i've solved parsing the json with a regular expression, extracting from "{{}}" the name of my key and then i call [GRMustacheTemplate renderObject: fromString: error:] to substitute the content, but i would like to know if there's another way! Thank you!!

Comment: OK, I got it. It looks like you need some rendering that is recursive: from "({{qd1}}+{{ad7}})*{{ad2}}" you render first "((2)+(9))*({{qd1}}+{{qd3}}+{{ad1}})" (wrapping the values with parenthesis so that you you respect the operator precedence), and then you render "((2)+(9))*((2)+(3)+({{qd1}}+{{qd3}}))", and then "((2)+(9))*((2)+(3)+((2)+(3)))", and then it's done. The computation of this expression is another topic (check http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/1553469975/abusing-nspredicate).

Comment: The wrapping of values with parenthesis can be done with the GRMustacheTagDelegate protocol.

Comment: The recursion ends when the tag delegate did not have to wrap any value: this means that no substitution has occurred, and that you now have an expression that can be evaluated.

Comment: Check this solution. If you have difficulties, please dare asking back :-)

Comment: Ok, more or less is what i'm doing right now! I wasn't (ab)using nspredicate but from that topic i'm really interested in NSExpression which is my next step! thank you very much!!

Comment: Cool :-) And thanks for NSExpression that I did not know about :-)